# Why isn't my animation working?

Tags: animation

fellow blender users.

I recently learned how to animate and I created a simple moving cube and that worked fine. Now I want to apply an animation to a lizard that I've modelled for a game. The lizard walks with its square legs shrinking and growing. So I've applied the scale keyframes (Because the legs are growing and shrinking) but the animation doesn't work! Please help.

Comment: Welcome to the site. Please edit your question and add more information and images that show your current setup. To get better answers please upload your file. You can use http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/.

Comment: Did you set up at least two keyframes? Are you sure that you have enough intermediate keyframes that lets the program understand that you are moving?